# Vapor - How to access the FluentValue type?

Tags: vapor

This is a Swift, Vapor related question.

How do I access the FluentValue type when trying to create a ResponseRepresentable Class?

The Vapor `Model` Protocol demands an ID; I want to assign my ID variable as a FluentValue optional.  However, I can't find it (even after Import Vapor & Import Fluent).

```
import Vapor
import VaporMySQL

let drop = Droplet()

drop.post(String.self, "boughtcoffee")     { request, buyerName in

   let coffeeledger = CoffeeLedger(name: buyerName, time: 0)

   guard let atLeastOneDrinker = request.data["drinker"].string else { 
       throw Abort.custom(status: .badRequest, message: "Please enter some drinkers")
}
     return coffeeledger
}
```

import Vapor
import Fluent

```
final class CoffeeLedger: Model {
    var id: FluentValue?
    var name: String
    var time: Int

    init (name: String, time: Int){
        self.name = name
        self.time = time
    }
}
```

I am following the Vapor video on setting up a Model that is Response Representable.  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E1ir7_s_VTw

Comment: btw - there is some background on https://vapor.github.io/documentation/fluent/model.html about this.  This code refers to a Node type.  However, I could not get that code to conform to Model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`FluentValue` became `Node` in Vapor 0.15. (Current version of Vapor at this time is 0.16).

Additionally, the `init` and `serialize` methods became `init(node: ...)` and `makeNode()`.

The code on the model page (https://vapor.github.io/documentation/fluent/model.html) should be up to date and working with Vapor 0.15 and later.

If there is a specific error you are getting, create another question here with that error message and I can try to help!

Answer (score 2):

Great.  That works beautifully.  The following is based on your documentation. Hopefully it helps others who are using Vapor:

```
import Vapor
import Fluent


final class CoffeeLedger: Model {
var id: Node?
var buyername: String
var drinkername: String
var time: Int

init(buyername: String, drinkername: String, time: Int) {
    self.buyername = buyername
    self.drinkername = drinkername
    self.time = time
}

init(node: Node, in context: Context) throws {
    id = try node.extract("id")
    buyername = try node.extract("buyername")
    drinkername = try node.extract("drinkername")
    time = try node.extract("time")
}

func makeNode() throws -> Node {
    return try Node(node: [
        "id": id,
        "buyername": buyername,
        "drinkername": drinkername,
        "time": time
        ])
}

static func prepare(_ database: Database) throws {
    try database.create("Ledger") { users in
        users.id()
        users.string("buyername")
        users.string("drinkername")
        users.int("time")
    }
}

static func revert(_ database: Database) throws {
    try database.delete("Ledger")
}
}
```